# How to place PHP value in HTML textarea

Tags: php, html, textarea

I'm trying to create a page where I can update MySQL data. I want the "current content" to already be visible in a box, so that it can be updated. But the box is too small.

I've tried using input and it works but only on one line, the data I want updated is a long paragraph. I tried using textarea but it doesn't seem to work.

`````````````````````````````````````````````````````````
<input type="text" name="comment" value="<?php echo $currentCategory['comment']; ?>" />

<input  type="submit" name="submit" value="Save Review"  />
````````````````````````````````````````````````````````
<textarea type="text" name="comment" value="<?php echo $currentCategory['comment']; ?>" />
</textarea>



I want the paragraph to fit in the box.
`````````````````````````````````````````````````````````

Comment: Textarea works differently to other inputs. Place your value between the textarea tags: <textarea> <?php echo $value ?> </textarea>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are writing the code wrongly as pointed out in the comment. You should write it like this:

```
<textarea type="text" name="comment"/>
  <?php echo $currentCategory['comment']; ?>
</textarea>
```

If you want the text area field not to be editable, then add `readonly`

```
<textarea type="text" name="comment" readonly />
  <?php echo $currentCategory['comment']; ?>
</textarea>
```